# Remove duplicates from a file and print in reverse statement not words using java

Tags: java

hi I need to remove duplicates from a file and print that file in reverse order for example "Ram is Ram is the Teacher" then output should be "Teacher the is Ram".

```
 public class BufferedReaderExample {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            BufferedReader br = null;

            try {

                String sCurrentLine;

                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));

                while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (br != null)br.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code currently does nothing expect printing each line. Also, the output is unclear: in case of duplicates, what do you want? Keep the first value? Keep the other one?

Comment: yes I want the first occurence be deleted and the last occurence to be printed for example "this is a this using this variable" it should print like variable this using a
I have not done anything except reading as I am unable to think the logic

Answer (score 0):

```
public void readAndPrintInReverseOrder() throws IOException {
    String path = "test.txt";

    BufferedReader br = null; 

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        Stack<String> lines = new Stack<String>();
        String line = br.readLine();
        while(line != null) {
            lines.push(line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }

        while(! lines.empty()) {
            System.out.println(lines.pop());
        }

    } finally {
        if(br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();   
            } catch(IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the above code is printing in way like if I have two lines in my file then it is printing the second line in place of first and first in place of second thats it but i think my question is clear in last comment

Comment: please guy please help me with this as this is very critical

Comment: Anyone who can answer this as this is really difficult for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.himanshu.factorypattern;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class DuplicateString {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String sCurrentLine;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try{
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/him.txt"));
            while((sCurrentLine=br.readLine())!=null)
            {   int c=0;
            //System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                String[] p = sCurrentLine.split(" ");
                Map<Integer,String> l = new TreeMap<Integer,String>();
                for(int i=0;i<p.length;i++){
                    if(l.containsValue(p[i])){

                    }
                    else{
                    l.put(c++,p[i]);
                    //System.out.println(l);
                    }
                }

                Set ss = l.keySet();
                Iterator it = ss.iterator();

                while(it.hasNext()){
                    //Map.Entry m =  (Map.Entry)it.next();
                    int k= (int)it.next();
                    System.out.print(l.get(k)+" ");

                //System.out.println(sCurrentLine);

            }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
        finally{
            br.close();

        }


        /*String s = "I am the logic the current the current";
        String[] p = s.split(" ");
        Map<Integer,String> l = new TreeMap<Integer,String>();
        for(int i=0;i<p.length;i++){
            l.put(p[i].hashCode(),p[i]);
        }
        Set ss = l.keySet();
        Iterator it = ss.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext()){
            //Map.Entry m =  (Map.Entry)it.next();
            int k= (int)it.next();
            System.out.print(l.get(k)+" ");

        }*/
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi I am done with what i want but now the problem is i have made some changes in my file and saved but my program is not reading the file May i know why?